# JavaFX-How to deal with multiple images using same controller function

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have a scrollpane full of images that can be dragged onto another pane in my scene (one image can be selected). The only problem is that they all have to share the same dragNdrop method in the controller class. I know that the fx:id has to be unique for each injectable node, so is there another way around this in JavaFX?

I even tried to add my images to an ArrayList in the controller class, creating an iterator to loop through each one in the dragNdrop method, but it doesn't work (For some reason giving me a NullPointerException). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to inject the nodes at all. If you detect a Drag&Drop gesture, you can get the node that triggered the event from the `Event` using [`Event.getTarget()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/Event.html#getTarget--). Here I assume only `ImageView`s can be the target for simplicity:

```
@FXML
private void dragDetected(MouseEvent event) {
    ImageView target = (ImageView) event.getTarget();
    // do something ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This clears up a lot, as I'm new to javafx.